# Replacing integers with strings within an array Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, int

Currently I have code that looks like:

```
def sudoku_generator

  @initial_board = [0] * 81

  a = (1..9).sort_by{rand}
  b = (1..9).sort_by{rand}
  c = (1..9).sort_by{rand}

  @initial_board[0..2] = a[0..2]
  @initial_board[9..11] = a[3..5]
  @initial_board[18..20] = a[6..8]
  @initial_board[30..32] = b[0..2]
  @initial_board[39..41] = b[3..5]
  @initial_board[48..50] = b[6..8]

  @initial_board[60..62] = c[0..2]
  @initial_board[69..71] = c[3..5]
  @initial_board[78..80] = c[6..8]

  @initial_board.each_slice(9) do |make_better|
    puts make_better.join(' | ')
  end

end

print sudoku_generator
```

This returns:

```
3 | 7 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
1 | 5 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
2 | 8 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 4 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 3
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 8 | 7
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 9
```

I am trying to find a way to now replace the zeros within this array with underscores "_". Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It does not affect the code, but what is "seduku"?

Comment: [Sudoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) misspelled.  Or perhaps alternatively spelled.

Comment: It does not affect the code, but what is "sedoku"?

Comment: Why not do `@initial_board = Array.new(81, "_")` from the beginning?

Comment: That Sudoku would probably appear in the paper on a Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sawa suggested in the comments, I'd default the array to `'_'`, but you can always just swap `0` for `'_'` as you print:

```
puts make_better.map { |x| x == 0 ? '_' : x }.join(' | ')
```

Comment: You can do `x.zero?`.

Comment: May as well use `map!`

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses. I learned something today. ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about using classes? It'a an object oriented language, right? I guess the method `#to_s` could have been prettier, though.

```
class Grid
  SIZE = 3

  def initialize
    @array = Array.new(3) { |line| Array.new(3) { |column| generator.call(line, column) } }
  end

  def generator
    proc { '_' }
  end

  def to_a
    @array
  end
end

class RandomGrid < Grid
  def generator
    @random_numbers ||= (1..9).to_a.shuffle
    proc { @random_numbers.shift }
  end
end


class DiagonalBoard < Grid
  def generator
    proc { |line, column| (line == column ? RandomGrid : Grid).new }
  end

  def to_s
    @array.map do |grids|
      grids.map(&:to_a).transpose.map do |rows|
        rows.flatten.join('|')
      end.join("\n")
    end.join("\n")
  end
end

puts DiagonalBoard.new
```

Outputs

```
9|2|8|_|_|_|_|_|_
5|3|7|_|_|_|_|_|_
1|4|6|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|8|1|5|_|_|_
_|_|_|6|2|9|_|_|_
_|_|_|3|4|7|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|2|9|1
_|_|_|_|_|_|7|5|6
_|_|_|_|_|_|3|8|4
```